# Enable authentication/access logging in conteneraized jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, logging, containers

I want to enable authentication/access logging in Jenkins instance, which is running in a container. Usually if it's not virtualized, I need to add the following in /etc/default/jenkins:

```
# Enable access log
JENKINS_ACCESSLOG="--accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access.log"
```

Unfortunate this file is missing in my container, can you please advise how can I setup it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in 2 possible ways:

```
docker run -d \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    jenkins/jenkins:lts \
    --accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger \
    --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined \
    --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access.log
```

or by building your own docker image:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

ENV JENKINS_OPTS --accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access.log
```

src: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md